# Can I use wp_widget_rss_output to show my site's feed in the dashboard?

Tags: widgets, errors, rss, dashboard, feed

I have a dashboard widget working and I'm trying to use [wp_widget_rss_output](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_widget_rss_output/) to display the site's [rss feed](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) in that area. The problem is that the only thing showing up is an error.

```
wp_widget_rss_output(array (
    'url' => get_bloginfo('rss_url'),
    'title' => get_bloginfo('name'),
    'items' => 10,
    'show_summary' => 1,
    'show_author' => 0,
    'show_date' => 1,
));
```

Error

> RSS Error: A feed could not be found at http://test.dev/feed/rss/. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.

How do I get rid of this error and show the actual feed? Currently I'm working locally but the problem is common.

from /feed

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    >
```

Comment: Are you using any http authentication on test.dev? I get this error when I use http authentication.

Comment: I don't think so, but then again, I don't really know what `http authentication` is. Would it just be easier to pull the data and parse it out of `wp_widget_rss_output`?

Comment: Is there an easy way to check if I am using http authentication?

Comment: I just had the basic (webserver) authentication in mind that we can setup in htaccess (AuthType Basic) or nginx (with auth_basic). I have it on my test.dev install and get the same error when I try to fetch the feed with `fetch_feed()`. When I remove that protection, it goes through as expected. You can try e.g. some public feed instead, just to check if that works.

Comment: Normally it would give "HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required" kind of response so SimplePie can't get access to the feed, as was the case on my install.